# Is it possible to install Ubuntu 14.4 from USB to Sony Vaio notebook

Tags: dual-boot, vaio

I have a sony vaio notebook with preinstalled Microsoft 8.1 version operating system. Now, I need to have a DUAL BOOTING system with Ubuntu (PenDriveLinux) distribution, installed alongside windows 8.1. Is it possible?.

Any pointers are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course it is possible, here is a list of what you need to do:

- Backup
- Resize the Windows partition using a Live CD
- Start the Ubuntu installation, and setting the Ubuntu partition on the now empty hard drive space
- Finish the installation

That is the short story.

Answer (score 0):

make the ubuntu 14.x dvd using brasero's iso option or startup disk creator and 
boot in to the ubuntu installation by selecting usb on boot option

use the custom install and select the installation run over the logical partition /dev/sdx1 .
when its turn of grub to install select the fisical pendrive /dev/sdx. 
IF YOU SELECT YOUR HDD/SSD you will brake windows grub and that is other post .

if you want to make the ubuntus disk in windows just mount the ubuntu iso in demons tools and paste all file in a cd and burn .

if you dont have a good usb3 or a thunderbolt its going to be slow .., so i let you a link to a persistence[persistance live](http://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-live-usb-install) usb